# Does A Contract Still Exist On The Blockchain After Gas Depletion?

Tags: blockchain, gas, evm, out-of-gas

From what I understand, a contract will still exist on the blockchain after it's associated account has been depleted of gas. However, the contract will no longer be executed by the EVM until more "fuel" is associated with said contract.

Does a contract still exist on the blockchain after gas has been depleted?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up concepts.

- What do you mean by the associated account of a contract? The deployed contract has its own address, its own life, and the lifecycle of the external account that deployed it has no bearing on the contract.
- The only way you interact with a contract is by sending it transactions.
- A contract does not expend gas on its own. All gas that is consumed is (at the moment) provided by the external account that sent the transaction.
- A contract exists even if nobody ever interacted with it after deployment / instantiation.
- A contract can hold Ether value. Even if its Ether value falls to zero, the contract still exists.